# AWS CloudFront in front of S3 and ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

everyone. I have a case about CloudFront + S3 + ECS(ALB).

- S3 bucket (enabled static web) (CSR - SPA) include:
  /index.html
  /admin
  /static/(file media)
- ECS + ALB: 1 cluster Fargate run web backend

So, the design like this picture:

[image: CloudFront + S3 + ALB]

I configured CloudFront behavior.

- Path pattern: /internal/* -> Origin ALB
- Path pattern: Default(*) -> Origin S3. S3 used the custom origin with s3 static web url not user the alias.

**Result**

When I request CloudFrontURL, it shows me the /index.html on the S3 bucket. (It's correct).

But when I request CloudFront/internal. It didn't show me the 404 code.
[image]

Then, I find the solution with lambda edge.

(link:

https://medium.com/radon-dev/redirection-on-cloudfront-with-lambda-edge-e72fd633603e

[Hosting multiple SPA web apps on S3 + Cloudfront under same URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692897/hosting-multiple-spa-web-apps-on-s3-cloudfront-under-same-url)

).

I modify the example code in the link. My code:

```
var path = require('path');
var url = require('url');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  // Extract the request from the CloudFront event that is sent to Lambda@Edge
  var request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

  const parsedPath = path.parse(request.uri);
  const parsedURL = url.parse(request.uri);
  // Extract the URI from the request  
  var olduri = request.uri;
  if (parsedURL.path.includes('/internal')) {
    var newuri = "EC2Co-EcsEl-1KE5FOHEHN2NH-230429797.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com";
    request.uri = newuri;
    console.log("alburi =" + " " + newuri);
  } else if (parsedPath.dir.includes('/') && parsedPath.base != 'index.html' && parsedPath.dir != '/admin') {
    var newuri = olduri.replace(parsedURL.pathname, '/index.html');
    request.uri = newuri;
    console.log("rooturi =" + " " + newuri);
  }
  // Return to CloudFront
  return callback(null, request);
};
```

**Result**

- When I request to the `CloudfrontURL/` or `CloudFrontURL/abcdxyz...` or `CloudFrontURL/something..` -> the response is the /index.html (Correct)
- When I request to the `CloudfrontURL/internal*` -> the response is 502. like this

[image]

Please, help me. Sry about my English skill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look the error, that means the cloudfront try to get the internal from S3 instead of the ELB.
I suggest you to change your behaviour to have more simple :

1.**Create a behavior that specifies a path pattern** to route all static content requests **to the S3 bucket**. For example, you can set the **"images/*.jpg"** path pattern to route all requests for ".jpg" files in the images directory to the S3 bucket.

2.**Edit the Default (*)** path pattern behavior and set its **Origin as your load balancer.**

Or you can have this for example, two behaviours to two origin

[image]

Comment: thank for your solution. i will try it. but my customer want the path **"/"** route to /index.html on s3 bucket. and the **"/internal** route to ALB.

Comment: do u have another idea?

Comment: i updated the solution used lambda edge.

Comment: @LamboOP, there is no need to use lambda atedge, you can just use behaviours, the problem with lambda is if you have new cloudfront, you must change the url dns in your lambda, check the image posted

Comment: oh. i re-config the behavious. then, it works without lambda edge. thanks for your help

Comment: Hey Lambo, could you tell me how can do that? I configured behaviours as yours and Hatim suggestion but it does not work.